# Implement MCOHTMLRendererIMAPDelegate in MailCore2 using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, imap, mime, mailcore2

Recently I've been trying to use MailCore2 inside my react-native app to read mails, so I made a RCTBridge in Swift for it, and I want to return a simple html string of fetched messages... I have successfully fetched messages of type `[MCOIMAPMessage]` and now I want to map over this array to convert it to html string with the following code

```
let msgs = (ret.value(forKey: "messages") as! [MCOIMAPMessage]).map{
    [
        "html": $0.htmlRendering(withFolder: folder as String,
                                 delegate: MCOHTMLRendererIMAPDelegate()) as NSString,
    ] as NSDictionary
}
```

Obviously it gives an error, can somebody please tell me the right way to do it...? Or at least tell me how to implement a MCOHTMLRendererIMAPDelegate

Comment: What error does it give? Also what is the type of ret? I guess it's an array of super class of MCOIMAPMessage - is the typecasting for all elements done correctly? Also this one does it correctly for plain text single messages, if it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56201795/how-to-get-message-body-and-last-email-in-mailcore2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589847/fetch-an-email-body-in-mailcore2-osx-with-swift